# How can a model field get the data from another model field?

Tags: django, django-models

I have a model in which I specify certain fields.

```
class Upload_files(models.Model):
    title           =models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True , null=True)
    image           =models.ImageField(upload_to='images')
    attributes      =models.ForeignKey(Product_attributes, blank=True , null=True)
    value           =models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True , null=True)
    price           =models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True , null=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
            return unicode(self.id)
```

Now i want to create another table which have only three fields(upload id, attribute id and value) . these fields must take the value from above table i.e., upload_id, attribute which i select above and also the value and is only readable from admin pannel.

I used the following code

```
class Product_values(models.Model):
    product         =models.ForeignKey(Upload_files, blank=True , null=True)
    attributes      =models.ForeignKey(Product_attributes, blank=True , null=True)
    value           =models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True , null=True)
    def __unicode__(self):
            return unicode(self.product)
```

I know does not work as i said but how can i do that,so that value and attribute field takes the value by default as i define it in upload_files model.

**EDIT**

I simply wants that when i insert the values in upload_files model from admin pannel , a instance of uploaded file is created in another table  with upload id , attribute  and value which i define earlier

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [post_save signal](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/signals/#post-save), and write and connect a receiver function that creates the Product_values entry like that:

```
def create_product_entry(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    # enter your code here

post_save.connect(create_product_entry, sender=Upload_files)
```

Comment: I used this but it does not create another table so can you show me one example of creating new table using this and inserting value in it.
**I have used like this**

`def create_product_value(sender, instance, **kwargs):
  
     drinker, new=Drinker.objects.get_or_create(product=instance)
post_save.connect(product_value, sender=Upload_files)`